# CodeIgniter Paging 404

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I've checked several threads on here regarding paging in CodeIgniter but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

I have a controller class located at controllers/admin/index.php called 'Index' that contains the following code:

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->helper( 'events_helper' );
        $this->load->helper( 'delegates_helper' );

        $this->load->model( 'admin/event_model' );
        $this->load->model( 'admin/delegate_model' );

        $this->load->library( 'pagination' );

    }

    public function index() {

        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->event_model->record_count();
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;

        $this->pagination->initialize( $config );

        $page = ( $this->uri->segment( 2 ) ) ? $this->uri->segment( 2 ) : 0;

        $data['paged_events'] = $this->event_model->get_paged_events( $config['per_page'], $page );
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_events();
        $data['event_courses'] = $this->event_model->get_event_courses();
        $data['event_suppliers'] = $this->event_model->get_event_suppliers();
        $data['event_venues'] = $this->event_model->get_event_venues();
        $data['event_locations'] = $this->event_model->get_event_locations();
        $data['event_statuses'] = $this->event_model->get_event_statuses();
        $data['event_prices'] = $this->event_model->get_event_prices();
        $data['event_types'] = $this->event_model->get_event_types();
        $data['event_tutors'] = $this->event_model->get_event_tutors();
        $data['event_delegates'] = $this->event_model->get_event_delegates();
        $data['event_delegate_statuses'] = $this->event_model->get_event_delegate_statuses();

        $this->load->view( 'templates/admin/header', $data );
        $this->load->view( 'admin/index', $data );
        $this->load->view( 'templates/admin/footer' );

    }

}
```

Now if I go to localhost/cream/public_html/admin the correct amount of results show and the links to the next pages render but when I click next or go to page 2 or 3, I get a 404 error.

Now I've tried changing my base url to:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/index';
```

and:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/index/';
```

and:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/';
```

While also changing my uri_segment to 1, 2 and 3 respectively but I get the same result.

I've even tried using:

```
$route['admin/(:num)'] = 'admin/$1';
```

and:

```
$route['admin/(:num)'] = 'admin';
```

Still, I get the 404 error.

These are my model functions in my 'Event_Model' class:

```
    public function record_count() {

        $this->db->select_sum( 'event_active' );
        $this->db->from( 'events' );
        $this->db->where( 'event_active', 1 );
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $total_active_events = $query->row()->event_active;

        if( $total_active_events > 0 ) {

            return $total_active_events;

        }

        return false;

    }

    public function get_paged_events( $limit, $start ) {

        $this->db->limit( $limit, $start );
        $this->db->where( 'events.event_active = 1' );
        $this->db->order_by( 'events.event_start_date', 'asc' );
        $query = $this->db->get( 'events' );

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {

            foreach ( $query->result() as $row ) {

                $data[] = $row;

            }

            return $data;

        }

        return false;

    }
```

I'm a bit stuck on this one and would appreciate your help. Thanks.

**EDIT: Added routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin/(:num)'] = 'admin/index/$1';
```

Comment: Can we know what's the URL of your 404? `localhost/cream/public_html/admin/index/2` I guess?

Comment: It's http://localhost/cream/public_html/admin/2 or if I change the 'base_url' to admin/index it then becomes http://localhost/cream/public_html/admin/index/2

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas on this one, I'm pretty stumped at the minute?

Answer (score 3):

`$route['admin/(:num)'] = 'admin/index/$1';` needs to reside in `config/routes.php`- you cannot add routes to controller methods.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that the $route is in the config/routes.php file and not the controller.

Comment: Yes, as I say it was in the routes.php file but it was also in the controller, as you can see in my edit above I've removed it from the controller and also added my routes.php code but the 404 still persists. Thanks.

Comment: Couple of things: given a url of `localhost/CI-install-dir/admin/index/` uri_segment setting should be `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;` I think, and your default controller in routes.php should be `$route['default_controller'] = "admin/index/";`.

Comment: The default controller is 'index' as it is the controller for the main part of the application which handles the frontend of the app/website. The actual install dir of the framework is localhost/cream, while the frontend and backend are accessed via localhost/cream/public_html, this is for security reasons, so the framework is actually outside of the public_html folder.

Comment: I must add, that this app is being developed locally on my mac, using MAMP.

Comment: Okay, but even then, with a url like `localhost/admin/index`your uri segment should be set to 3, no? Admin = 1, index = 2

Comment: Yes, though as I mention in my original question I've tried 1, 2 and 3 respectively with no joy?

Comment: Shouldn't your default controller be `$route['default_controller'] = "admin/index";`, since you mention the index.php controller is in a folder called admin?

Comment: I've changed $config['uri_segment'] = 3; and $page = ( $this->uri->segment( 3 ) ) ? $this->uri->segment( 3 ) : 0; but still no joy, I've even gone up to 6.

Comment: Check my routes advice above. Also, I don't think you need this in there: `$route['admin/(:num)'] = 'admin/index/$1';`

Comment: The index controller in the 'admin' folder is to manage the index of that directory and the admin section, I will also have an index controller at public_html/ which will be the main/default controller.

Comment: If I change the default controller to anything else, it breaks the application.

Comment: Yeah, just tried again and I get 404 errors all over the app.

Comment: Obviously, I've got two classes called Index, and two controllers called Index, one located at 'controllers/admin/index' and also 'controllers/index', which I thought may have been causing a conflict but I tested them both and they both loaded their respective views. Anyway, I renamed the admin controller to admin.php and changed the class name to Admin, then added a route like, $route['admin'] = 'admin/admin'; Everything else in the app still works great, except for this pagination. It's doing my nut in. :-(

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've figured out what is going on.

When accessing a paged result other than the first page I was at the URI 'localhost/cream/public_html/admin/$1', where $1 represents the page number.

In my 'Admin' controller code, under the index() function, the '$config['uri_segment']' property value needed to be set to 2. This alone wouldn't have fixed the issue but it was the correct URI segment.

Next, I needed to add the following 2 routes to 'routes.php':

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/admin';
$route['admin/:num'] = 'admin/admin';
```

The first route was because I had now changed my controller class name to 'Admin' and its filename to 'admin.php', so I needed a route that would work when the user was at the following URI:

```
localhost/cream/public_html/admin/
```

The second route was to reroute the page number to the correct controller, which was now 'admin/admin'.

That was it. My pagination is now working.

All I need to do now is get it to change the '$limit' variable so that it can be dynamically changed via a drop down. I should be able to pass the value of the dropdown to $_POST and pull it in to my 'get_paged_events();' function in my model. I'll let you know how I get on.

Cheers for all the help folks.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid **index** from your paging just follow the below step

Step1: customize /config/routes.php

```
   $route['controller/(:num)'] = "controller/index/$1";
   It convert your url www.yourdomian.com/controller/(number) to www.yourdomain.com/controller/index/(number)
```

Step2: Customize your pagination code with **$config['uri_segment'] = 2** like below

```
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'controller/';
        $config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['total_rows'] = (your total rows);
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have url rewriting on your web server? If don't then try localhost/path/to/codeigniter/index.php/admin. If you want to skip the index.php then read about mod_rewrite (if you are using apache) and check the codeigniter's user guide for site_url function that might be useful to generate in-site urls.