# When I click to the next page on pagination,it goes to 404 error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

In my `News.php`controller,i'm having the below code:

```
 public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Database Details';

    $config     =   array();
    $config['base_url'] =   base_url("news/index");
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->news_model->record_count();
    $config['per_page']     =   5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    //$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
 // $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

    $choice  =  $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] =  round($choice);

     $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page   = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    //echo "page--".$page;
    $data['user_data']  = $this->news_model->get_details($config['per_page'],$page);
    $data['links']          =  $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');   
    echo $this->db->last_query();       

    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);   

    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

In my `News_Model.php` model,The below code is exists:

```
 public function get_details($limit,$start)
{    
    //echo "Limit---".$limit."</br>";
    //echo "Start---".$start."</br>";
      $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
      $query = $this->db->get('user_data'); 
      return $query->result_array();    

 }
```

My view file `index.php` shows :

```
 <h3>
   <?php echo $title; ?>
 </h3>
 <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Email</th>
       <th>Mobile</th>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
       //print_r($user_data);
     foreach ($user_data as $user_item): 
   ?>
   <tr>

      <td><?php echo $user_item["user_name"];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $user_item["address"];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $user_item["email"];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $user_item["mobile"];?></td>
     <td><a href="edit?id=<?php echo $user_item["id"];?>">Edit</a></td>
     <td><a href="delete?id=<?php echo $user_item["id"];?>">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>

 </tbody>
 </table>
 <p class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

In my `config.php`:

```
 <?php
      $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/';
      $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
 ?>
```

If i remove $config['index_page'] = ''; my other pages are not displayed.

In my `route.php` :

```
  <?php
    $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/index/$1'; //explain what does it actually means?
    $route['news'] = 'news';
    $route['default_controller'] = 'news/create';
    $route['(:any)'] ='pages/view/$1';

 ?>
```

The above code displays like follow:

[image]

But when i click `page 2` it shows as :
[image]

Please don't suggest [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116316/codeigniter-pagination-link-go-to-404-page-not-found), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227764/codeigniter-paging-404) and [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116316/codeigniter-pagination-link-go-to-404-page-not-found).I have seen the above links but no idea how to get it:(

Kindly guide me!!

Comment: open `config.php` change `$config['index_page']='index.php';`

Comment: @viral its already like you mentioned only

Comment: @Viral When my link is like:http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/news/index/2 this it will display.Now i want to know that how do get index.php in between that?

Comment: if you type `index.php` is it works??

Comment: @Abdulla at the same time my query comes as `SELECT * FROM `user_data` LIMIT 2, 5` its wrong know:( it should be after 5th record know,like `SELECT * FROM `user_data` LIMIT 5, 5` son on

Comment: change this to `'news/index/$1'` this `'news/index.php/$1'` and check

Comment: no it `404 error` is for all the pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in your router

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['default_controller'] = 'news/create';
$route['(:any)'] ='pages/view/$1';
```

and place .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 01**

```
<?php

    $data['title'] = 'Database Details';

    $count = $this->news_model->record_count()

    $config['base_url'] =   base_url(). 'index.php/news/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $count;
    $config['per_page']     =   5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $limit = $config['per_page'];

     $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page   = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['user_data']  = $this->news_model->get_details($limit,$page);
    $data['links']    =  $this->pagination->create_links();


    $this->load->view('templates/header');   
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);   
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Comment: I have tried it ji....but same is happening:( but can u explain What is the use of htaccess?

Comment: its remove` /index.php` part in your url

Comment: yes ji, my url is like this `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/news/index/5`. But this is what i'm getting from earlier:(

Comment: `$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/index/$1';` keep empty this and check once

Comment: you mean `$route['news/(:any)'] = '';`?

Comment: remove every thing `$route['news/(:any)'] = '';`

Comment: removed `base_url` and `index` in config??

Comment: yes `$config['base_url'] = '';` and `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: wait will post you working pagination with bootstrap style.

Comment: but i think we are almost close

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81168/discussion-between-abdulla-and-keerthi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81275/discussion-between-php-learner-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;` and then check.

Also why you have 2 routes :

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/index/$1'; //explain what does it actually means?
$route['news'] = 'news';
```

Comment: When i click the second page it will show `http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/news/index/5` in my address:(

Comment: When my link is like:`http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/news/index/2` this it will display.Now i want to know that how do get `index.php` in between that?

Comment: I accept it for removing `use_page_numbers`, Because when i removed it,i can get resolve the query problem,but the page goes to 404